# removing trimming special characters

Tags: ios, swift

I've been trying to trim and remove characters from:

```
{
    "data":
    {
        "is_silhouette": false, 
        "url": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/13254063_1039990606071446_7680951628744860479_n.jpg?oh=e5088fb1a981041f60c9abde6762d892&oe=57C12344"
    }
}
```

and convert it at something like:

```
https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/13254063_1039990606071446_7680951628744860479_n.jpg?oh=e5088fb1a981041f60c9abde6762d892&oe=57C12344
```

Here is my code :

```
let dataStore = backend.persistenceService.of(Users.ofClass())
    dataStore.find(
        { ( users : BackendlessCollection!) -> () in
            print("Users have been fetched  (ASYNC): \(users)")
            let page = users.getCurrentPage()
            for userx in page {
                print(userx.picture)
            }

        },
        error: { ( fault : Fault!) -> () in
            print("Server reported an error (ASYNC): \(fault)")
        }
    )
```

Comment: Is that one string or a dictionary?

Comment: please post any relevant code. How have you attempted to do this?

Comment: ... thats JSON, you don't need to trim it, you need to parse it. Please format your question to display the data more easily. Its very difficult to read

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are reading from response.

The URL you want and response URL are both same.

So no need to trim it, you can get the URL from the response directly by using **valueForKey** or **objectForKey** method.

```
var URL: String = data.valueForKey("URL") as? String
```

Comment: [ let dataStore = backend.persistenceService.of(Users.ofClass())
    dataStore.find(
        { ( users : BackendlessCollection!) -> () in
            print("Users have been fetched  (ASYNC): \(users)")
            let page = users.getCurrentPage()
            for userx in page {
                print(userx.picture)
            }
            
        },
        error: { ( fault : Fault!) -> () in
            print("Server reported an error (ASYNC): \(fault)")
        }
    )
]